# mock objects in python are not working on Jenkins?

Tags: python, jenkins, mocking, nosetests

I have a method, which needs to be mocked dependend on params. e.g.:

`mock_obj.method('param1').get()` returns `10`

`mock_obj.method('param2').get()` returns `'~/Programs'`

etc.

I do that using side_effect:

```
def method_mock(*args, **kwargs):
    param_name = args[0]
    pref = MagicMock()
    pref.get.return_value = {
        'param1': 10,
        'param2': "~/Programs"
    }[param_name]
    return pref

mock_obj = MagicMock()
mock_obj.method = MagicMock(side_effect = method_mock)
```

then I call the mock:

```
>>> mock_obj.method('param1').get()
10
>>> mock_obj.method('param2').get()
'~/Programs'
```

Everything is working fine on my machine. But when I run tests (using nosetests) on CI server(Jenkins) then I get this:

```
>>> mock_obj.method('param1').get()
<MagicMock name='mock_obj.method().get()' id='22379152'>
>>> mock_obj.method('param2').get()
<MagicMock name='mock_obj.method().get()' id='22379152'>
```

However when I run above code from console (on CI machine) then it is working fine...

**EDIT:**

After whole day I found a solution. The problem is with nosetests. 
When I was using one command to run all tests I got issue described above:

```
nosetests --with-xunit --all-modules
```

When I run each test separately...everything is working:

```
nosetests --with-xunit test_integration1
nosetests --with-xunit test_integration2
nosetests --with-xunit test_integration3
nosetests --with-xunit test_integration4
```

Any idea how to fix it to be able to run all tests with one command?